# Fetch Multiple Api URLs And Store Data In An Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, api

I am trying to store the fetched  Data  In to an array that contain its name and price.
But the problem is on browser window the result of only one.with either of SCBTC or XLMBTC..On Several refresh it will Toggle.Can i get these two queries at the same time in 2 lines,And can i store it seperatly?Is it Possible?

```
<body>
    <div id="a"></div>
</body>

<script>
    "use strict";

    var pair = ["SCBTC","XLMBTC"];
    var url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=";


    for(var i=0; i<2; i++) {

      fetch(url + pair[i])
        .then(function(resp) {
          return resp.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          console.log(data); 

          var x = document.getElementById("a");
          x.innerHTML= JSON.stringify(data); + "<br/>"; 
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Since you write both the results to the same div, only the last one to arrive back from the server will be shown. So either use multiple divs, or add to the innerHTML instead of replacing it completely.

Comment: ok...i understand..but to switch them to multiple div elements?how can i identify each data returned?

Comment: That should be inside whatever `data` is no?

Answer (score 0):

You an use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get multiple results:

```
<body>
<div id="a"></div>
</body>

<script>
"use strict";

    var pair = ["SCBTC","XLMBTC"];
    var url = "https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/price?symbol=";


    Promise.all(
      pair.map(p=>fetch(url+p).then(r=>r.json()))
    ).then(
      results=> {
        console.log(data); 
      }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: shows nothing..one open bracket is missing after argumentlist..when i put that it shows data is not defined :-(

Comment: @Aashiq Didn't close the map() bracket, you should see something in the console now.